# Contextual, time-based apps/websites

Tags: real-time-updates

Looking to find some apps/websites that do a good job with contextual, time-based information. As in, say, the app reminds you at 5:30pm to eat a healthy dinner. Or tells you at 8:00am not to forget to grab your coat on your way out to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for theory, take a look to this [Real Time Design Patterns](http://archive.oredev.org/download/18.5bd7fa0510edb4a8ce4800019179/Bruce_Douglass_-_Realtime_design_Patterns.pdf) paper by Bruce Douglas

Else, if you're looking for visual aids, the [Moves](https://www.moves-app.com/) and [WeightWatchers](http://www.weightwatchers.com/templates/marketing/marketing_utool_1col.aspx?pageid=1191351) Apps are really good examples, since they do specifically what you mention.

[image]
[image]

Also, you can take a look to these [**mobile patterns**](http://pttrns.com/?scid=27) and [notification patterns](http://inspired-ui.com/tagged/notifications) for ideas

Comment: As much as love minimalistic design I really don't like that first example (not that it's not a good example). I suppose it may be designed for apple watches too.